# error svn: SSL handshake failed: SSL alert received: Ilegal parameter

Tags: svn, ssl, handshake

I am trying to update my working copy in subversion with Linux and I get this error:

SSL handshake failed: SSL alert received: Illegal parameter

It does not work for a new check out. It works in windows using TortoiseSVN.

I have upgraded the subversion to the version 1.6.17 but it does not work either.